# Exception when trying to attach a java process to visual studio debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, visual-studio-2013, jna

I have some C code in a DLL which is being called from Java. So I want to debug the code and see where it is failing. I started debugging the code in Java and debug view opened there. Then I went to visual studio and attached that java process for debugging in visual studio. I had put break points in both java code and visual studio code. When I continued the debugging in Java after attaching the process I got the following exception when the very first time the code was going to enter visual studio.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8B23DDD27 (msvcr120.dll) in javaw.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.
```

Why am I getting this exception? Is this related to the code or some debugging setting? Please advice.

Comment: Sounds like the debugger is catching your failure before it actually fails.  Show your native declarations, your Java declarations, sample native usage, and your actual Java usage.

Comment: Yeah managed to find it! thanks a lot mate! :)